# Gerar arquivo texto a partir de uma aplicação console application

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, stream

Preciso adequar esse método de uma aplicação `Windows Forms` https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet para `Console Application`, ou seja, ao invés de usar o objeto `saveFileDialog.ShowDialog()` tenho que criar o arquivo utilizando outro método da classe `Stream`:

> Método Usado na aplicação Windows Forms:

```
public void GeraArquivoCNAB400(IBanco banco, Cedente cedente, Boletos boletos)
{
    try
    {
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Arquivos de Retorno (*.rem)|*.rem|Todos Arquivos (*.*)|*.*";
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ArquivoRemessa arquivo = new ArquivoRemessa(TipoArquivo.CNAB400);

            //Valida a Remessa Correspondentes antes de Gerar a mesma...
            string vMsgRetorno = string.Empty;
            bool vValouOK = arquivo.ValidarArquivoRemessa(cedente.Convenio.ToString(), banco, cedente, boletos, 1, out vMsgRetorno);
            if (!vValouOK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("Foram localizados inconsistências na validação da remessa!", Environment.NewLine, vMsgRetorno),
                                "Teste",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                arquivo.GerarArquivoRemessa("0", banco, cedente, boletos, saveFileDialog.OpenFile(), 1);

                MessageBox.Show("Arquivo gerado com sucesso!", "Teste",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Preciso adaptar para ser usado em uma aplicação Console Application.

Comment: O que você precisa exatamente? Me parece que é só tirar essas partes que são do Windows Forms e substituir por um valor fixo.

Comment: Como eu faria para substituir pelo valor fixo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas tire as dependências de `System.Windows.Forms`. `SaveFileDialog` e `MessageBox` são duas coisas que você não poderá usar, pois eles fazem parte do namespace `System.Windos.Forms`.

Como o caminho do arquivo está vindo do **`SaveFileDialog`**, você terá que passar o caminho "manualmente" ou desenvolver alguma função que possibilite o usuário de escolher este caminho (não parti pra este lado porque não está especificado na pergunta).

Eu coloquei as mensagens dos `MessageBox` no console.

```
public void GeraArquivoCNAB400(IBanco banco, Cedente cedente, Boletos boletos)
{    
    ArquivoRemessa arquivo = new ArquivoRemessa(TipoArquivo.CNAB400);

    //Valida a Remessa Correspondentes antes de Gerar a mesma...
    string vMsgRetorno = string.Empty;
    bool vValouOK = arquivo.ValidarArquivoRemessa(cedente.Convenio.ToString(), banco, cedente, boletos, 1, out vMsgRetorno);

    if (!vValouOK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Foram localizados inconsistências na validação da remessa!", Environment.NewLine, vMsgRetorno));
    }
    else
    {
        arquivo.GerarArquivoRemessa("0", banco, cedente, boletos, new FileStream(@"C:\PastaQualquer\Arquivo.txt", FileAccess.Write), 1);
        //No lugar de C:\PastaQualquer\Arquivo.txt você coloca o caminho do arquivo

        Console.WriteLine("Arquivo gerado com sucesso!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Tire todas partes do Windows Forms. O nome do arquivo que está vindo de `saveFileDialog.OpenFile()` será substituído, em linhas gerais, por (exemplo):

```
new FileStream("caminho do arquivo aqui", FileAccess.Write);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/StreamWrite.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Pode variar conforme a necessidade.

Outras formas podem ser mais adequadas dependendo da situação.

Comment: Muito bem funcionou.